# What are the sets of integral values for the equation $x^3 + 11^3 = y^3$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Does the solution use Fermat's Last Theorem because i kind of used that.
And by the way this question came up in my maths olympiad mock test.

Comment: For example, $(x,y)=(0,11)$ is a solution. And by the way, $x^3+y^3=z^3$ was already proved by Euler in $1770$ (that there is no integral solution with $xyz\neq 0$). So no need to use Fermat's Last Theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $11^3=(y-x)(x^2+xy+y^2)$ we get $y\in\{x\pm1,x\pm11,x\pm121,x\pm11^3\}$.

Since $x^2+xy+y^2\geq 0$ we have $y-x\geq 0$ and so $y\in \{x+1,x+11,x+121,x+11^3\}$

Since $(y-x)\leq(y-x)^2 < y^2-yx+x^2$ we have $(y-x)<(11)^{3/2}$ and so $y\in \{x+1,x+11\}$.

First case gives $((x+1)^2-x(x+1)+x^2)=11^3\implies x^2+x+1=11^3\implies (x+\frac{1}{2})^2=11^3-\frac{3}{4}=\frac{11^3\times 4-1}{4}\implies x=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{11^3\times 4 - 1}}{2}$ which is not even rational.  The expression in the radical is a whole number one less than a multiple of $4$ so cannot be a square.

Second case gives $11((x+11)^2-x(x+11)+x^2)=11^3\implies x^2+11x+11^2=11^2\implies x(x+11)=0 \implies x= 0$ or $-11$

Comment: You don't need to let WLOG $x<y$ because it is already always true. We have $x^2+xy+y^2=(x+(1/2)y)^2+(3/4)y^2>0$ because $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$. Therefore the other factor $y-x$ is also positive.

Comment: Good point${}{}{}{}$. So $4$ cases

Comment: Also, you don't need to check the cases $x\pm 121$, $x\pm 11^3$, because $0<y-x\le(y-x)^2<x^2+xy+y^2$ if $xy\neq 0$.

Comment: oh, good point. So $2$ cases.

Comment: Let me add that.

Comment: It should be $y-x\le (y-x)^2$. If $y-x=1$, then $y-x=(y-x)^2$.

Answer (score 4):

note that $$y^3-x^3=(y-x)(y^2+xy+x^2)$$

Answer (score 1):

By Fermat last theorem there are non with $xyz\ne 0$.

Comment: OP already mentioned Fermat's last theorem and also there are no non-zero solutions. There are the solutions $(x,y)=(0,11), (-11,0)$.

Comment: $-11^3+0\neq 11^3$

Comment: @JorgeFernández The equation is $x^3+11^3=y^3$. If $(x,y)=(-11,0)$, then $(-11)^3+11^3=0^3$.